# how to call a function_A inside function_B in order to get a function_A returns

Tags: python-3.x

I called onClicked2 method inside onClicked method in order to print the result of onClicked2 fuction what it returns. But print results "None" it should print "First Selection" if check box is selected

```
def onClicked(self):
        
        if self.radioButton.isChecked() and self.pushButton.isChecked():
            print("Radiaobutton1 is checked: "+str(self.radioButton.text()))
            print(self.onClicked2(self))

def onClicked2(self,selection2):
    
    if self.checkBox.isChecked() and self.pushButton.isChecked():
        selection2="First Selection"
        print("Memn2n is checked: "+str(self.checkBox.text()))
        
    elif self.checkBox_2.isChecked() and self.pushButton.isChecked():
        selection2="Second Selection"
        print("Bidirectional is checked: "+str(self.checkBox_2.text()))
        
    elif self.checkBox_3.isChecked() and self.pushButton.isChecked():
        selection2="Third Selection"
        print("GRU is checked: "+str(self.checkBox_3.text()))
        
    return selection2
```

Comment: `self.onClicked2(self)` in your code put `self` as the `selection2` argument, is that what you want?

Comment: There are a few issues I can see here. You are passing `self` into  `onClicked2` , which has an odd signature. Try removing the `selection2` argument and call `print(self.onClicked2()` in `onClicked`. The `self.pushButton.isChecked()` in your conditions in `onClicked2` also seem redundant (you know this must be true for the function to be called in the first place). Are any of the `print` statements being called at all? Could you add the output to your question?

Comment: after removing selection2 argument getting this error "return selection2

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'selection2' referenced before assignment"

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting OnClicked2 inside OnClicked function.

Comment: it's better to give some eg.

Comment: tried your suggestion but, it did not print the value of selection2 that is assigned in onClicked2 funtion